# Showing an error to find max number string in array by combining elements in java

Tags: java, arrays, max

**Problem: Given an array of numbers, arrange them in a way that it forms the largest value.**
Given a list of non-negative integers nums, arrange them such that they form the largest number and return it.

Since the result may be very large, so you need to return a string instead of an integer.

Input: 
[54, 546, 548, 60] 
Output: 
6054854654

Code:

```
public class SortNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] arr = {111311, 1113};
        sortArray(arr);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + "");
        }
    }
    public static int[] sortArray(int[] arr){
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                String a = "" + arr[i] + arr[j];
                String b = "" + arr[j] + arr[i];
                int x = Integer.parseInt(a);
                int y = Integer.parseInt(b);
                if(x > y){
                    int temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Input: [111311, 1113] 
Output: 1113111311 (Giving an error for this)

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "111311111311"
            at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
            at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
            at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
            at SortNumber.sortArray(SortNumber.java:15)
            at SortNumber.main(SortNumber.java:4)
```

Can someone tell me how can I solve this error.

Comment: you can use BigInteger

Comment: ... or a long, because 111311111311 is out of the range of an integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you sort the numbers as numbers, it's not the optimal order. If you sort them as **strings**, they are.

```java
public static void sortArray(int[] nums) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
            String one = String.valueOf(nums[i]) + nums[j];
            String two = String.valueOf(nums[j]) + nums[i];

            if (one.compareTo(two) > 0) {
                int temp = nums[i];
                nums[i] = nums[j];
                nums[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

***P.S.** I am thinking about a performance. Looks like, if you able to use data structures like `Map`. You can increase a performace from `O(nˆ2)` to `O(n * log(n))` with a bit more code.*

```java
public static void sortArray(int[] nums) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> numCount = countNumbers(nums);
    Collection<Integer> unique = sortAsString(numCount.keySet());
    int i = nums.length - 1;

    for (int num : unique) {
        int total = numCount.get(num);

        for (int j = 0; j < total; j++)
            nums[i--] = num;
    }
}

private static Map<Integer, Integer> countNumbers(int[] nums) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (int num : nums) {
        map.merge(num, 1, Integer::sum);
    }

    return map;
}

private static Collection<Integer> sortAsString(Set<Integer> nums) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();

    for (int num : nums) {
        map.putIfAbsent(String.valueOf(num), num);
    }

    return map.values();
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, and I suspect this is the point the teacher was trying to get across.  If you sort the numbers as numbers, it's not the optimal order.  If you sort them as STRINGS, they are.

Answer (score 1):

The number formed by concatenating the two array elements is too large to be stored in an `int`. You can use `long` or `BigInteger` instead, depending on how large the input can be.

```
long x = Long.parseLong(a);
long y = Long.parseLong(b);
```

Note, however, that it is not necessary to work with numeric types at all for this sort of problem. Think about how `String` representations can be manipulated instead.